# How to upload a folder through FTP?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a folder (and its content) through FTP but when I try to do it, I keep getting an error saying no file is selected.

**Do you know any way to make it so it'll upload the folder and its content?**

Here's the code I am using. (I want to upload all the files in the folder Plugins):

```
UploadFile(@"C:\\MainPlugins\\Plugins", "ftp://testsiteurl.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/test plugin", "username", "password");
```

This is the sub I am using:

```
public void UploadFile(string _FileName, string _UploadPath, string _FTPUser, string _FTPPass)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo _FileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName);

    // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest _FtpWebRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(_UploadPath));

    // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass);

    // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    // after a command is executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;

    // set timeout for 20 seconds
    _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000;

    // Specify the command to be executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Specify the data transfer type.
    _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;

    // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length;

    // The buffer size is set to 2kb
    int buffLength = 2048;
    byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];

    // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead();

    try
    {
        // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        System.IO.Stream _Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        int contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

        // Till Stream content ends
        while (contentLen != 0)
        {
            // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
            contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
        _Stream.Close();
        _Stream.Dispose();
        _FileStream.Close();
        _FileStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI is incorrect, you need to specify the file name in the URI.

```
// Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest _FtpWebRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(_UploadPath + "/" + _FileInfo.Name));
```

Also, consider using the "using" keyword for your streams to properly dispose them in case of an exception.

```
using (System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead())
                {

                    // Stream to which the file to be upload is written

                    using (System.IO.Stream _Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
                        int contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

                        // Till Stream content ends
                        while (contentLen != 0)
                        {
                            // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                            _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                            contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                        }

                        //No need to Close the file stream and the Request Stream

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where do I put the first line of code you created? You dont call the sub UploadFile.

Comment: Still I cant upload a folder

Comment: I merely edited the code in your UploadFile method. 

If you want to upload a folder you'll have to iterate through the files in the folder in a loop and use the Ftp.MakeDirectory method beforehand.

Either way this is probably not how you would want to upload files. You should modify your method to be asynchronous.